# Gitlab API to get size of commit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

We have a self-hosted Gitlab setup. I am trying to get the size of each commit(basically the number of additions and deletions) using API. To achieve that I am using the below API endpoint which gives these stats in response as shown on [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-a-single-commit).

`GET /projects/:id/repository/commits/:sha`

For normal commits, the stats which are provided by the above endpoint are exactly the same as the GitLab application but commits that are generated after merging a branch differ by huge margins.

Is it the correct way to get these stats or is there any different API endpoint that will help me? I did search in the docs but did not find any.

Comment: `but commits that are generated after merging a branch differ by huge margins.` Can you provide an example of this? Or show what number it is you're looking for? Every commit SHA will always give the same stats before and after merge as far as I can see. Are you doing something other than a normal merge commit?

Comment: Yes, you are right stats are the same in each case. After I posted this question I came across that, it is not about merge commit as I posted in the question. Now the issue is with one of the commits.

Comment: This particular commit is "Showing 9 changed files with 17 additions and 8 deletions" on the GitLab application, but when I fetch a single commit using API in response the stats show it as     

` stats: {
        additions: 242822,
        deletions: 98,
        total: 242920
    }`

Comment: This commit includes one .storyboard file whose file size is more than 10MB. Do you know how GitLab calculates these stats in case of such non-code files?

Comment: The stats come from gitaly, which [internally uses `git diff --numstat -z`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/blob/5997ef7cc293c30d219de2dafa763a9c60b0bc43/internal/gitaly/service/diff/numstat.go#L21-24). I don't think `git` cares if a file is "non-code" or not. I'm not sure, but it might be ignored in some cases based on `.gitattributes` like for binary files or git LFS perhaps -- but knowing the behavior of `git diff --numstat` would tell you one way or the other.

Comment: I've spent the last hour or so trying to reproduce the behavior you described committing a variety of large/small binary and nonbinary files on `gitlab.com` and haven't been able to reproduce. Reliably, the API always matches the UI. Binary files are not counted in both cases. Perhaps you are using an older self-hosted version of GitLab that may have a different behavior? If possible, can you try to create a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes its seems like a version issue, my current self-hosted gitlab version is 11.3.1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your findings on this issue

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, this is likely caused by your version of GitLab. There have been several issues addressing git stats since GitLab v11. In particular, it seems that large files (those which are collapsed) were largely ignored in the diffs UI [until 11.4](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/20282) when the gitlay diffstats client was implemented.

The issue does not seem reproducible on gitlab.com